# How do I make a PictureBox jump in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have an assignment for school where I have an animated character that runs.  I need to be able make him jump and return to the spot he started the jump after a button press.  I have a timer that switches images to animate the character.  There are also buttons to speed up, slow down, start, and stop the character.  I'm having trouble because I think I have to integrate the timer into the button press and I'm not too sure how to to that.  There is a space at the bottom of the code where the jump button is.  I'm able to make him go up but can't figure out how to make him come back down.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub tmrSpeed_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrSpeed.Tick

    Static Dim intCounter As Integer 

    picRunner.Location = New Point(picRunner.Location.X + 15, picRunner.Location.Y)

    If picRunner.Location.X >= 523 Then
        picRunner.Location = New Point(-25, picRunner.Location.Y)
    End If

    Select Case intCounter
        Case 0
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r0
        Case 1
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r1
        Case 2
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r2
        Case 3
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r3
        Case 4
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r4
        Case 5
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r5
        Case 6
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r6
        Case 7
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r7
        Case 8
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r8
        Case 9
            Me.picRunner.Image = My.Resources.r9
    End Select

    intCounter += 1

    If intCounter >= 10 Then  
        intCounter = 0
    End If


    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnFaster_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFaster.Click

    Try  
        Me.tmrSpeed.Interval = Me.tmrSpeed.Interval - 10
    Catch x As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("He can't run any faster!")
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnSlower_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSlower.Click

    Me.tmrSpeed.Interval = Me.tmrSpeed.Interval + 10

End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click

    Me.tmrSpeed.Stop()

End Sub

Private Sub btnRun_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRun.Click

    Me.tmrSpeed.Start()

End Sub

Private Sub btnJump_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnJump.Click


End Sub
End Class
```

How would I go about implementing the jump?  My teacher says I have to use a loop, obviously to check when the picturebox reaches a certain hot but I can't figure out how to use this with the timer.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

set a loop that calculates force.

also make a variable for the rate of decay for that force.

have the loop apply the force by subtracting it from the current y position
and after it apply force subtract the rate of decay from it to decrease the force so the next time the loop happens the force is lesser and it begins slowing down.

also have a global variable called gravity to create a constant pull on the object downwards so when the upward force decays it will go back down.

The rest you must figure out, if this is an assignment then it is very important for you to develop the logic to do what i described without someone giving you the answer. It will give you better understanding of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same assignment, and I came to this following code as my solution. I set the initial interval of the timer to 999999 so that the form wouldn't load with the animation jumping.

```
Private Sub btnJump_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJump.Click
    Me.tmrJump.Interval = 100
    Me.tmrJump.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub tmrJump_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrJump.Tick
    Static intOldTop As Integer
    Static intCounter As Integer
    Dim intStep As Integer = 5

    If intCounter = 0 Then intOldTop = picSpaceRunner.Top

    intCounter += 1

    Select Case intCounter
        Case 1 To 15
            picSpaceRunner.Top -= intStep
        Case 16 To 30
            picSpaceRunner.Top += intStep
        Case Else
            picSpaceRunner.Top = intOldTop
            intCounter = 0
            tmrJump.Stop()
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class